# How to properly dump mysql database via mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

Does mysqldump utility requires any seperate client ??

I'm using MYSQL5.5 command line client for windows..

I'm writing query

```
mysqldump -u root -p pwd** my_db > mydb.sql
```

I'm getting the error

```
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax t
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're running the command in the MySQL command line client. Run it from a shell instead, not inside of the client.

In other words, open a normal shell (cmd.exe if using Windows), and run: (your path to mysqldump.exe will no doubt differ)

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump -u root -ppwd** my_db > mydb.sql
```

Do *not* open up the MySQL command line client and run that command inside of there. That client is for executing SQL; the mysqldump.exe program is completely separate and runs on its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know i'm on the right track now.. I'm getting error access denied for root@localhost .

Comment: Do not use a space between -p and the password. So if the password is Secret01 then use `mysqldump -u root -pSecret01`

Comment: @nl-x +1 Excellent comment. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I tried with no space between -p and password but the issue seems with some priviledges.

Answer (score 0):

```
> not <
```

You're dumping the file mysql.sql INTO mysqldump, not out of it

Comment: Sorry for the typo... Corrected

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u root -p pwd** my_db > mydb.sql
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo... Corrected